How to link XFPLA and XVBAP in MV45AFZZ during sales order creation?
In include MV45AFZZ, form USEREXIT_SAVE_DOCUMENT_PREPARE, during sales order creation, is there a way to link data from XFPLA to XVBAP ?
I need to know which item a particular billing plan is tied to.
XVBAP-FPLNR_ANA is not populated.
